# Automated Testing using ReadyAPI (SoapUI NG)

Tags: java, web-services, ready-api

I'm just getting started with **ReadyAPI(SoapUI NG)** to do automated testing for our Spring based project. So using the ReadyAPI documentation I successfully tested REST URI calls using below steps:

> 1. Created a project:    File > New Project > Create a Project using REST URI
> 2. It creates a project structure like below:    REST Project > URI > createAccount < Request 1
> 3. In the Request window I added my parameters by using xml/json.
> 4. After Running the Request I'm getting my desired response.
> 5. I also checked Assertion that also giving desired results.

I did all this using  [ReadyAPI Documentation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/)

**My questions are below:**

1. How to achieve Automated Testing using ReadyAPI(SoapUI NG)?
2. What features of ReadAPI are generally used? How to use them effectively?
3. What are the differences between SoapUI NG, LoadUI NG, SoapUI, ReadyAPI? (I thinks these are just different versions, not sure though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try to answer them to my best of abilities.

- How to achieve Automated Testing using ReadyAPI(SoapUI NG)?

> Ready API or SoapUI are the automation tools themselves. To manually
>   test the         APIs, there are other tools like swagger. However if
>   you are planning to automate the flow of your whole project and
>   planning to use some sort of architecture/framework which will enable
>   you to do a lot more than just execute the tests at once then you can
>   try using tools like Jenkins.

- What features of ReadAPI are generally used? How to use them
  effectively?

> One of the most talked about things in Ready API is Data Driven
>   Testing. If you follow this approach, then you may use test steps like
>   DataGen, DataSource, DataSink, PropertyTransfer, Groovy Assertions,
>   Groovy Script Step, JDBC Step. Those are the steps that are used
>   widely in Ready API Projects.

- What are the differences between SoapUI NG, LoadUI NG, SoapUI,
  ReadyAPI? (I thinks these are just different versions, not sure
  though)

> Ready API is a collection of different API testing solutions, like
>   Performance Testing(LoadUI), Security testing(Secure), Functional
>   testing (SoapUI). When you install Ready API, you install all the
>   solutions together. And then you can chose to buy licence for each of
>   those solutions separately.

Hope that answers your question.